# Inconsistent processing of the form-data POST with multiple files

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

I have a script in python to test posting multiple files to a certain end point. Here is the script:

```
import requests
url = "https://endpoint.com/api/upload"
payload = {}
files=[
  ('images',('image01.png',open('H:/image01.png','rb'),'image/png')),
  ('images',('image02.png',open('H:/image02.png','rb'),'image/png'))
]
headers = {}
response = requests.post(url, files=files)
print(response.text)
```

It's generalized of course. But, when I test this script the endpoint receives only 1 file! instead of 2.

If I test this exact script on `https://webhook.site/` for example - still 1 file instead of two.

Multiple sources keep suggesting this exact layout/structure for the `files` array. However, it's almost nowhere mentioned that the actual approach should be a little different, providing a different file id/name in each tuple:

SOLUTION:

```
files=[
  ('images01',('image01.png',open('H:/image01.png','rb'),'image/png')),
  ('images02',('image02.png',open('H:/image02.png','rb'),'image/png'))
]
```

Only in this case, the endpoint gets 2 files.

My question is: is there an official, correct reference in the requests docs that documents properly how to POST multiple files?

Comment: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#post-multiple-multipart-encoded-files Looks like you're doing it right.  Maybe the endpoint isn't accepting them properly?

Comment: @JohnGordon My endpoint is an azure function in python. very simple. very basic. I thought maybe there is something how azure passes the http req to the function that messes it up. So i tried to route my test script to `https://webhook.site/` and observed the same behavior there = 1 file instead of 2 and if you change the names = 2 files.